# Runtime error when my DbContext file inherits from IdentityDbContext and not DbContext

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am trying to add authorization and and authentication to an ASP.NET entity framework program. I'm new to it and it's doing my head in.

I originally had a Context class that inherited from `DbContext`. Now that I'm trying to add security I have to inherit from `IdentityDbContext` but when I do this I get an exception in my `Program.cs` file on the line `context.Database.EnsureCreated();`

My DbContext which is `SchoolContext.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using AdvisementApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AdvisementApp.Data
{
public class SchoolContext : IdentityDbContext //Inheriting 
{
    public SchoolContext (DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<AdvisementApp.Models.Student> Students { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Advisor> Advisors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Major> Majors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MajorCourse> MajorCourses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>().ToTable("StudentCourse");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Major>().ToTable("Major");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Advisor>().ToTable("Advisor");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MajorCourse>().ToTable("MajorCourse");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Advisor>()
           .HasMany(a => a.Students)
           .WithOne(s => s.Advisor)
           .HasForeignKey(s => s.AdvisorId);
    }
}
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using AdvisementApp.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'SchoolContext' not found.")));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<SchoolContext>();
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
// Password settings.
options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

// Lockout settings.
options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

// User settings.
options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
// Cookie settings
options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
// The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
 var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

 var context = services.GetRequiredService<SchoolContext>();
 context.Database.EnsureCreated();//This is where I am getting the error.
 DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});
app.UseAuthentication();
//app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

This is the error: [image: Image of Exception]

Am I intending to do something incorrectly?

Comment: can you please share your .csproj file?

Comment: So you inheriting? Then where you allow base class to create/define its part of models?

Comment: @GuruStron I don't think I have a .csproj file, I'm using .net core 6.

Comment: .NET Core does not forbid csproj files)))

Comment: @Selvin, do you mean my DbInitializer class?

Comment: @Selvin I would guess this is [`IdentityDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0) from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`. =)

Comment: *DbInitializer* No... Error is asking to add something "somewhere"... But it's not talking about any of your entity class... So you cannot add this... But maybe base class would do this if you allow it to do this "somewhere"

Comment: @GuruStron like I said, I'm new to .net core but I haven't created or used any files with the .csproj extension and I don't have one in this current project.

Comment: You know what `override` keyword is?

Comment: Yes I do know what the override keyword is

Comment: @NewDev How have you created your project? Are you using some IDE? Try opening the folder with the project and check if there are some files. How do you install nugets?

Comment: Is previous implementation called when you override?

Comment: @Selvin Yes I am using visual studio 2022 I found the .csproj file, when I open it, it's just my DbInitializer file. Is this what you want to see? I use Manage NuGet Packages to install NuGet packages

Comment: No, when you override base class method is not called... Fix it

Comment: Ok but how exactly do I fix that? That's where I'm lost

Comment: call base method in method from the exception